# Magento2 product review captcha

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

I want to rewrite Magento-review layout `catalog_product_view.xml` to show Recaptcha on a product review. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your requirement?

Comment: actually i am using extension for catpcha its add on login account create pages now i want to add the captcha in product review form and extension add captcha in other place by rewirte layout files like customer_account_create.xml in the extenions view forntend layout folder so now how i do it for prdouct review

Comment: If you want to create custom module to implement native Magento captcha in product review form, then I can suggest the steps. Please let me know.

Comment: yes but gooole captcha

Comment: MSP\ReCaptcha currently i am using this extension

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add reCaptcha validation code.

Comment: checkout https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Comment: @test, have you reviewed my answer? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I assume that you are okay with modifying Msp Recaptcha module.

> Step 1: Open /vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/adminhtml/system.xml and paste below code before `</group>` tag

```
<field id="enabled_review" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="230" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
    <label>Use in Product Review</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    <depends>
        <field id="enabled">1</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

This will add review page option in the reCaptcha settings.

> Step 2: Create new file under  /vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and paste below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
                   template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">review</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 3: Override form.phtml by editing /vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/frontend/di.xml file.

Add the following code in di.xml file (just before `</config>` tag) mentioned above to override template file.

```
<type name="Magento\Review\Block\Form">
    <plugin name="review-form-override" type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Plugin\Block\Review\Form" />
</type>
```

> Step 4: Create a block file /vendor/msp/recaptcha/Plugin/Block/Review/Form.php and paste below code:

```
<?php
namespace MSP\ReCaptcha\Plugin\Block\Review;

class Form
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Review\Block\Form $block)
    {
        $block->setTemplate('MSP_ReCaptcha::review/form.phtml');
    }
}
```

> Step 5: Edit /vendor/msp/recaptcha/Model/LayoutSettings.php file and add the following line just after `'contact' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendContact(),`:

```
'review' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendReview(),
```

> Step 6: Edit /vendor/msp/recaptcha/Model/Config.php file and define the following constant where other constants have been defined:

```
const XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND_REVIEW = 'msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_review';
```

> Step 7: In the same file (/vendor/msp/recaptcha/Model/Config.php) add the following function just before closing braces of class:

```
public function isEnabledFrontendReview()
{
    if (!$this->isEnabledFrontend()) {
        return false;
    }

    return (bool) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND_REVIEW);
 }
```

> Step 8: Now copy **form.phtml** file from **`/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates`** and paste it into **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/templates/review`** folder.

then

> Step 9: Add the following code in the form.phtml file under **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/templates/review`** folder:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
```

Above code should be pasted just before the following:

```
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
```

This will add the reCaptcha in the review form.

If you want code for validation of captcha also, please let me know. I will update soon.

**Update: Steps for reCaptcha validation**

Since this module is validating reCaptcha using **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/Observer/ReCaptchaObserver.php`**, I tried to find call to this observer, but could not find direct call to this observer.

But I found definition of validation observers in **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/frontend/events.xml`**, so follow from step 10 now.

> Step 10: Edit **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/frontend/events.xml`** and add below code just before `</config>` tag:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post">
    <observer name="msp_captcha" instance="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\ReviewFormObserver" />
</event>
```

The observer classes defined in **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/frontend/events.xml`** file don't exist. Instead they are being replaced by virtualType.

> Step 11: Add the follwoing code just before `</config>` tag in **`/vendor/msp/recaptcha/etc/frontend/di.xml`**:

```
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\ReviewFormObserver"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\ReCaptchaObserver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="isCheckRequired"
                      xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\ReviewForm</argument>
            <argument name="failureProvider"
                      xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ReviewFormObserver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ReviewFormObserver"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ObserverRedirectFailure">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="redirectUrlProvider"
                      xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\ReviewForm</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\ReviewForm"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\IsCheckRequired">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="enableConfigFlag"
                      xsi:type="string">msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_review</argument>
            <argument name="area" xsi:type="string">frontend</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\ReviewForm"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\SimpleUrlProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">cms/index/index</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Now the only problem remaining is redirecting to correct URL if reCaptcha validation fails. Currently I have redirected to **`cms/index/index`** action.

Please share the code if you get success in redirecting to the product URL on which the user filled the review.

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I have checked till Magento 2.2.x. It has no native support for captcha in review module.

Answer (score 1):

Using this catalog.product.view.xml filed not show, because there is no container (form.additional.info )available on review layout.
Please use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
           <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info">
               <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
                      template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                   <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">review</item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
           </container>    
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and call in template file:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
```

Comment: Shockingly, nobody vote up this correction.

Answer (score 1):

Further explanation of Mohit Kumar Arora's answer, where he said;

> Now the only problem remaining is redirecting to correct URL if
>   reCaptcha validation fails. Currently, I have redirected to
>   cms/index/index action.

Note: Keep in mind the answer from Lokesh Rathore also

Create your custom class to redirect to the product page, it is pretty easy but requires logic.

```
<!--Failure Redirect-->
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ReviewObserver" type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ObserverRedirectFailure">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="redirectUrlProvider" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\UrlProvider</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Rather inject another **virtualType** into **redirectUrlProvider**, create your new class e.g. `Custom\Module\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\UrlProvider` with following content.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl;

use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrlProviderInterface;

class UrlProvider implements RedirectUrlProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    private $responseRedirect;

    /**
     * UrlProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param RedirectInterface $responseRedirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectInterface $responseRedirect
    ) {
        $this->responseRedirect = $responseRedirect;
    }

    /**
     * Get redirection URL
     * @return string
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->responseRedirect->getRefererUrl();
    }
}
```

Take a close look to the above code, it is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3 it works by default. You have to enable "MSP\ReCaptcha", configure it in backend panel and everything works :)